# How to split EntrySet into map with streams in Java 8

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `Map<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>> map = new HashMap<>();`

I have to count the number of votes and put it in a new map grouped by localDateTime. I don't know how to do this with a stream.

My return value must be `Map<LocalDateTime, Integer>`.

How to do this using streams in Java 8 ?

Thanks

Comment: Number of votes is determined by Set size or some `Vote` class property?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you search for similar problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a `Map<LocalDateTime,Set<Vote>>`, the `Vote` instances are already grouped by `LocalDateTime`. All you need to do is sum the vote values for each `Set<Vote>`:

```
Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> voteSums = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                 e -> e.getValue()
                                       .stream()
                                       .mapToInt(Vote::getVoteValue)
                                       .sum()));
```

Where you should replace `getVoteValue` with the actual name of the `Vote` class method that returns the value you wish to sum.

Or if you just wish to know how many `Vote` instances there are for each key, you can write:

```
Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> voteCounts = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                 e -> e.getValue().size()));
```